# Conditionally encapsulate rules

Tags: less

Let's say I have the following:

```
@import 'hello.less'
```

Based on a variable value, I want to nest this inside another class. The following is what I want to accomplish, in *pseudocode*:

```
if(@someVar = true):
  .someClass {
    @import 'hello.less'
  }
else:
  @import 'hello.less'
```

I guess I could use mixin guards, but I don't know how to handle the 'else' case:

```
.someClass when (@someVar = true) {
  @import 'hello.less'
}

// Else?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`not`](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature-guard-logical-operators) and [`&`](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature)(`&` expands to nothing if its parent is the global scope ([e.g.](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature))):

```
@some-var: true;

.some-class when (@some-var) {
    @import (multiple) "hello";
}

& when not(@some-var) {
    @import (multiple) "hello";
}
```

Note that [`multiple`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-multiple) import option is required in this case since both imports are always evaluated and the guards only control if the content appears in output or not.

**---**

Though in general I wonder why you need to keep the code for different projects in the same file and control its compilation indirectly via variables. Instead I'd suggest to create just "namespaced hello" file:

```
.some-class {@import "hello";}
```

and import it unconditionally in the project you want it that way.

Comment: There is one project/code base that compiles to slightly different outputs. This is one of the minor differences between them.

Comment: @mostruash: This answer is in my opinion better than your own (no offence).

Comment: @Harry, It is, indeed. But I have a question: if I put `@import` statement into a mixin and replace them accordingly in your example, do I still need the `multiple`?

Comment: It depends only on how many times import is actually appearing in the code. Imports are always evaluated before anything else. So if you have one `import "hello"` you don't need `multiple`, if you have two or more you need it - even inside a mixin (like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/0b3de4a39aed9538f200) for example) - imports are still evaluated when the compiler parses the mixin definition (not when the mixin is invoked).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Thanks for that. I didn't know imports are evaluated immediately even when within a mixin.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is as follows:

```
@someVar: true;

.someClass when (@someVar = true) {
  .main(false);
}

.main(@someVar);

.main(@x) when not (@x) {
  @import 'hello.less'
}
```

I'll mark this as the answer unless someone has a better one.

Comment: By no means a wrong answer but as stated elsewhere I think the other answer is better. Still vote for the effort :) Quite a lot of people post a question and just wait unlike you.