# Conditional Imports in Less

Tags: less

I've tried two ways of doing optional imports but neither seems to be working. Is this possible as of less 2.6.0?

```
@useRTL: true;

& when (@useRTL = true) {
    @import "bi-app/bi-app-rtl.less";
}

@useRTLpath: "bi-app/bi-app-rtl.less";
@import (optional) "@{useRTLpath}";
```

Comment: First of all `"true"` is not equal to `true`. But the actual mistake in your code is missing `(multiple)` - for more details see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212979.

Comment: Actually, the second import is just there to prove that both the conditional and its inverse dont work. It doesnt actually belong in the final code. Also, the quotes were just for testing.

Comment: And by "don't work" you mean... what? [Here](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40useRTL%3A%20true%3B%5Cn%5Cn%26%20when%20(%40useRTL%20%3D%20true)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40import%20%5C%22https%3A%2F%2Fgist.githubusercontent.com%2Fseven-phases-max%2Fe80c9935c679ec15c1a9%2Fraw%2F292639ecab672cbe70a7d42c1119c7a7c4635414%2F35460595.less%5C%22%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D) you can see it works as expected.

Comment: Your right that the syntax works (I handt realized that). It seems that I cannot get the variable to match when injecting as `modifyVars`

Comment: "match when injecting as modifyVars" - Here's `modifyVars` [example](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/xZembP?editors=1010) and it still works.

Comment: Yes, the feature works. But its not working for me. Going to close this issue as I have a workarounds and it doesnt seem like were getting any closer to a solution. Thanks for trying!